# Issue calling Web service from Android browser

Tags: android, browser, service, web

I have been working on calling a simple web service in html5 from Android Browser(Android 2.2). Its not working on Android browser. But, it works if i run it on a PC. Nothing happens when i click the button. I have been on net for couple of weeks now. But, didn't get anything to work. Below is the code of the html page. please help.

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>UseSwap</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
     function InitializeService(){
      service.useService("http://localhost:2913/WebServicesUsingCSharp/WebService.asmx?wsdl",
    "GetAgeService");

     }
     var StrYear, StrMonth, StrDay;
     function GetAge(){
      StrYear = document.DemoForm.StringYear.value;
      StrMonth = document.DemoForm.StringMonth.value;
      StrDay = document.DemoForm.StringDay.value;
      service.GetAgeService.callService("GetAge", StrYear, StrMonth, StrDay);
     }
     function ShowResult(){
    alert(event.result.value);
      }
     </script>
    </head>
     <body onload="InitializeService()" id="service"
    style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)" onresult="ShowResult()">
       <form name="DemoForm">
       Year : <input type="text" name="StringYear"/>
       Month : <input type="text" name="StringMonth"/>
       Day : <input type="text" name="StringDay"/>
       <button onclick="GetAge()">Get Age</button>
      </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Regards,
Parshant.

Answer (score 1):

your html references a service on the same machine
    http://localhost:2913

i dont think that you have the webservice running on your android phone.

replace `localhost` with the ip of your server

Comment: I tried replacing "localhost" with the server IP address. But, it didn't work.

Comment: is the server reachable from the android phone? i.e. can you get a html page of your service from you phones html-broser?

Comment: I'm running the code on Emulator. When i try to call web service from html page loaded on Android Emulator, nothing happens.

Comment: As per the previous comments, you will need to be able to access the "server" from other machines. If this is a local development machine ensure that it has the relevant ports open in the firewall.